# Input'ы с одинаковым именем в цикле. их идентификация в обработчике.

Tags: массивы, input, while, циклы, обработка

У меня есть форма редактирования (изменить количество и удалить) выбранных пользователем товаров. Сама форма формируется циклом, то есть имеется 2 inputa:

```
<input type="number" name="col" class="coltbl" value="<?php echo $row['tvr'];?>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="delite" value="<?php echo $row['tvrid'];?>" />
```

Важно: кнопка "Сохранить" находится за пределами цикла - общая на весь вывод товаров.

Задача в том, что не понятно как в обработчике инициализировать редактируемый товар. И если чекбокс несет в своем арсенале необходимую информацию через value (это id редактируемого товара), то вот с первым инпутом проблемы: в value - количество и идентифицировать его с конкретным товаром проблематично...

Вспомнил про массивы:

```
name="col[<?php echo $tvrid;?>]"
```

И теперь не понимаю что делать дальше в обработчике.
Спасибо!

Comment: > delite

**delete**

Лучше всего делать вот так:

    <input type="number" name="products[<?= $row['tvrid'] ?>][number]" class="coltbl" value="<?= $row['tvr'] ?>" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[<?= $row['tvrid'] ?>][delete]" value="true" />

После этого в `$_POST` окажется симпатичный массив `products`, в котором ключами будут айдишники товаров.

Comment: понял только одно: надо понять что такое массивы. пошел читать.
если раньше было хоть и смутно, но все-таки понятно что делать в обработчике, то теперь непонятно вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался! Спасибо большое!
Сделал так:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
$products=$_POST['products'];
foreach ($products as $id => $value) {
    $tvr=strip_tags(trim($value['number']));
    mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET tvr='".$tvr."' WHERE tvrid='".$id."'");
    if (isset($value['delete'])) {
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM cart WHERE tvrid='".$id."'");}
}}
```